# Selector failing in jquery 1.8+

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Any idea why this selector should fail?

```
$('.Demographics :input["data-name"]')
```

You can see it [here at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jb2TA/).

I'm trying to get all the `input` elements that have a `data-name` attribute.

In jquery 1.9, I get this:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Demographics :input["data-name"]
```

Comment: Interestingly, this did work in jQuery 1.7 and before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
$('.Demographics :input["data-name"]')
```

to

```
$('.Demographics :input[data-name]').length
```

Demo; [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jb2TA/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Removing the quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have quotes around the attribute name, only the attribute value.  `"data-name"` is not a valid attribute name.  Only `data-name` is:

```
$(".Demographics :input[data-name]")
```

However, for values you can use quotes:

```
$(".Demographics :input[data-name='test1']")
```

The latter is not necessary, but is recommended.

Comment: Thanks! As per html, quotes would be needed only if there is a space or special character in the value string.

Comment: @GlenLittle that is correct, but they will still work even if there is not a special character, so I would recommend using them at all times for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.Demographics').find('input[data-name]').length
```

Or just:

```
$('.Demographics :input[data-name]').length
```